# Flutter doctor script throws errors and then crashes

Tags: git, batch-file, flutter

When I run `flutter doctor -v` I get a couple of uncaught errors and then a crash.

Output below:

```
C:\Users\philb>flutter doctor -v
'git rev-parse HEAD' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
'dir /a:l "c:\Users\philb\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\" 2>nul   | find ">     bin [" 2>nul' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.11.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.407], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 0.11.9 at c:\Users\philb\flutter
    • Framework revision d48e6e433c (5 days ago), 2018-11-20 22:05:23 -0500
    • Engine revision 5c8147450d
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

|CreateProcessW failed 2
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 7c60cb5645c44cdd)
\CreateProcessW failed 2                                                                                               Crash report written to C:\Users\philb\flutter_02.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
```

Here is `PATH` and `PATHEXT` environment variables:

```
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\philb\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Dart\dart-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\philb\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;c:\users\philb\flutter\bin
```

`PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`

The CMD window can find `git`

```
C:\Users\philb>where git
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

Just for S&G I put some debug in `flutter.bat` and `PATH` and `PATHEXT` are OK just before it invokes `git`. The only thing done to `PATH` is that the `flutter.bat` script adds the location of another version of "git" (mingit) to the `PATH` but that doesn't seem to matter. Even if it uses that version the same error results. The script invokes `git` via a `for /f` loop/

The script code in flutter.bat looks like this:

```
PUSHD "%flutter_root%"

  FOR /f %%r IN ('git rev-parse HEAD') DO SET revision=%%r

POPD
```

I checked and `flutter_root = /users/phil/flutter/bin`

I noticed that the flutter directory is read only after extracting. But I do have "all control" as far as I know. I tried to change that but after a complex session as local admin I failed to clear the read only flag but not sure if that is a red herring! I can try again if someone has a thought about what's up!

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. I had installed the latest version of **JAVA** and that has seemed to overwrite `ComSpec` to point to their version of `cmd.exe`. Bad move as I think that is what the CMD tool uses to start a child CMD. Reverted to the system32 version and it all works.

The fix:

- Open **Control Panel** – **System** – **Advanced system settings** and click on button **Environment Variables**.
- If environment variable `ComSpec` is set to anything other than `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe` expanding usually to `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`, then reset it to Windows default `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`.

Mine was set to `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jcmd.exe`. Thanks Oracle!!!